# Correlation of two independent variables

Tags: statistics, correlation

Sorry if this is a basic queation, but I have some numbers and I'm asked to find the correlation between these two variables. 
My first variable (A) contains some values for a parameter which is measured by a human (let's say height of some objects). The second variable (B) contains some values collected by a device for the same set of objects.
I simply calculated the absolute difference and percent different. But how define correlation here? My variables are independent right? Is there any r value for two independent variables?
Example values:

A   2  4  5   7   10 18   37
B   3  4   3  7    16  20   35

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The correlation is defined as $$ \frac{E(AB)-E(A)E(A)}{\sigma_A\sigma_B}$$ and the most common estimate of this quantity is the sample correlation $$ R = \frac{\sum_{i=1}^n (a_i-\bar a)(b_i-\bar b)}{\sqrt{\sum_{i=1}^n(a_i-\bar a)^2}\sqrt{\sum_{i=1}^n (b_i-\bar b)^2}}$$

where $\bar a$ is the sample mean $\bar a= \frac{1}{n}\sum_i a_i.$ So start by taking the average of the $a_i$ and $b_i$ and then plug it into this formula.

I will do a very simple example for reference. If you had $A =(1,2,3)$ and $B=(2,3,4)$ then $\bar a = 2$ and $\bar b = 3$ and $$\sum_i (a_i-\bar a)^2 = (1-2)^2+(2-2)^2+(3-2)^2 = 2.$$ Similarly, $\sum_i(b_i-\bar b)^2 = 2 $ and $ \sum_i(a_i-\bar a)(b_i-\bar b) = 2.$ So you have $$ R = \frac{2}{\sqrt{2}\sqrt{2}} = 1.$$ They are perfectly correlated. (You can see this because when you plot them against each other you get a straight line.)

The variables are hopefully not independent if your device and the human are any good at measuring heights. (And from eyeballing the example I think it's safe to say there's a significant correlation here.)

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I don't exactly get what is the dependence in my example. How two different methods to measure height of some objects can be correlated? I can understand the amount of food we eat and the weight we gain are two dependent variables. But how can i justify in my example?

Comment: @user8296976 They are dependent cause they are both measuring the height. The result of one measurement gives you statistical information about the other. For instance if the human measures 70cm and both methods are accurate to about 1cm then we can be pretty sure that the machine will measure around 69-71cm. However, it might be reasonable to assume that the *errors* in the two measurements are independent of one another.

Comment: Does it matter if the length of variable A and B are different? For example, variable A only contains 5 numbers and B contains 20 numbers! Thanks

Comment: @user8296976 yes. It doesn't make any sense otherwise. The idea is that $(a_i,b_i)$ are samples from a joint distribution.